# Screen switching in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image: Image_1]

The above emulator image is just summing up the given two values and showing  the result on the below textview which is on the same screen.

Here my need is i want to show only the result on another screen's textview.How to achieve 
this? what source i have to add on my source?

```
public class CheckingActivity extends Activity {
 Button     button1;
 EditText   txtbox1,txtbox2;
 TextView tv;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     txtbox1=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
     txtbox2=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
         String a,b;
         Integer vis;
         a =  txtbox1.getText().toString();
         b =  txtbox2.getText().toString();    
         vis =  Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);
         tv.setText(vis.toString());
        }
    });
```

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: where is the other screen?explain your problem

Comment: [Let me do it for you ?](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=android+pass+data+between+activities&oq=andriod+pass+&aq=4l&aqi=g-l10&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.4.0i13l10.1102.15798.0.21448.68.48.11.0.0.2.1006.16168.6j11j7j1j3j9j4j2.48.0...0.0.emmLyPtfgoA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) Replace your main activity with this:

```
public class CheckingActivity extends Activity {
 Button     button1;
 EditText   txtbox1,txtbox2;
 TextView tv;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

 txtbox1=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
 txtbox2=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) 
{
     String a,b;
     Integer vis;
     a =  txtbox1.getText().toString();
     b =  txtbox2.getText().toString();    
     vis =  Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);
     //tv.setText(vis.toString());
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("sum",vis.toString());
     startActivity(i);
    }
```

---

3.) Add one xml layout file `resultview`

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvsum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sum : " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvsum"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

4.) Finally add in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ResultActivity" />
```

---

Hope it helps!!

### EDIT

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;
String result;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.resultview);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    result = extras.getString("sum");
    }
tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvres);    
tv.setText(result);
  }
 }
```

Comment: if i followed your source,on ResultActivity   the following line is showing error,    tv.setText(result);

Comment: Mr.GAMA its working fine.Thanks a lot for providing this solution.thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want to show a new activity with the result value. If so, you can do this by create a new activity and pass to this activity an integer value symbols that value.

You can do this like this:

In CheckingActivity activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
     String a,b;
     Integer vis;
     a =  txtbox1.getText().toString();
     b =  txtbox2.getText().toString();    
     vis =  Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);
     Intent in = new Intent(this, B.class);
     in.putExtra("output_value", vis);
     startActivity(in);

    }
});
```

Xml for your new activity:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Output: "/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_value"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_sum"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the new activity:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int value = extras.getInt("output_value");

    TextView output =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_value);
    output.setText(value);
```

Comment: @OfirAN just some string to identify the value, that way I can get his value in the new activity. You can put anything you like Instead that string, as long you get your value with the exact same string in the new activity.

Comment: @andro prabu the value that you want to pass to the new activity, e.g the output value - 144 in your example above.

Comment: you mean,here i am just getting the input values from the user and displaying it in textview,so have i to mention the textview's object name instead of "yourIntValue" right?

Comment: @andro prabu Update my answer. You need to create a new activity with the textView you want. Then you pass your a+b value from the onClick event to the new activity. In the new activity you need to get the new value with Bundle and set the textView with that value.

Comment: @andro prabu Updated my answer.

Comment: I have tried your both answers,really its working well.Thanks for spending your precious time with me...thanks a lot